# output html page after rendering

Tags: php, html

Good day all!

I would like to be able to get contents of an HTML document after rendering, using PHP. example, if I have this HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function(){
            /* some dummy code here*/
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div> 
                <a href="some_links"> click here friend </a>
                <input type="button" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit atmen</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the output of the function should look like:

**click here friend**

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit atmen**

Thanks in advance for your help!
Note: please do not care much about this HTML code, it's just an example

Comment: @Mani it is joke or you are serious?

Comment: You'll need a bot that executes javascript.

Comment: @m02ph3u5  I don't know what a bot is, I ll do some research. but I 'd like to remind you that I want to run this with php, not javaScript...

Comment: Thought you wanted the output as the browser displays it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output buffering should do the job:

```
<?php
   ob_start();
?>

all of your HTML

<?php
   $content = ob_get_content();
    echo strip_tags($content);
?>
```

Comment: Hi @iyop45, it seems that the php code must be in the HTML document....  what if the HTML document is in a separate file?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue  then use ```include(...);``` to reference your HTML document. Just make sure you output its content after you start the output buffering and before you get the buffer content.

Comment: Hi. I did as you said. It printed it out. Problem is, it still prints the whole HTML code, not just the text inside....

Comment: @PhoenixBlue Oh you want to be able to get just the text of the HTML document and not the tags? This would involve parsing the HTML document (which will be the ```$content``` variable). ```strip_tags($content);``` might be useful for you. You didn't specify in the question that you didn't want the HTML..

Comment: I said what the output should look like. But I ve tried the strip_tags function, even though it still shows the content of the script function, I think I can deal with that. I ll add some more parsing to achieve what I want. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You would have a PHP file and use [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

For example.

**index.php**

```
<?php
  function getHTML() {
   include 'test.html';
  }
  getHTML();
?>
```

**test.html**

```html
<html>   
    <body>
        <form>
            <div> 
                <a href="some_links"> click here friend </a>
                <input type="button" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit atmen</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @RemanBroder.  I have tried your code, but it outputs the whole html code... I just ran: 

$ php index.html

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The HTML is called by the PHP file. If you open the PHP file on your localhost for example you will see the HTML rendered correctly. That looks like you ran the php in your terminal and a terminal won't render HTML.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the update. Tough my code may require that the php script is ran on terminal....

Comment: Can you expand on what your goal is and any requirements? Should help us give a clearer/better answer.

Comment: Well, I was generating some html codes, to display. problem is, some of those html codes are "empty". in other words, they didn't display a thing, because they were just full of javascript functions, php stuff, but the browser doesn't display that. So Before uploading that file (somewhere else) I needed to make sure that the user would see something on that page (cuz the final user is just interested in the final renedered page). So I wanted to see if there is any "significant" information first... Hope I m making some sense there...

Comment: OK, I think I have got you. You want to see how the HTML is displaying? You can just save the HTML file and open it in the browser if you can't use a browser and are using Linux [this] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/58416/how-can-i-preview-html-documents-from-the-command-line)  has some useful info for showing HTML in a terminal.